# Different result in subtracting the two values

Tags: javascript

I subtract the two values`(2.75 - 2.475)` in javaScript. I got the value `0.2749999999999999`. And when I check in the calculator, I got different result `0.275`. What is different between in calculation of javaScript and calculator?

Comment: In the calculator it is rounded off

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix precision

```
var d =2.75 - 2.475
var result = d.toFixed(3)
```

Comment: I would like to know that does javaScript used the different calculation for it.

Comment: Actually 0.2749999999999 goes up to max precision supported by decimal in Javascript. It is even for calculator but it will round of for you. I don't know much but some calculator have some setting to get more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try rounding it off:

```js
var res = parseFloat((2.75 - 2.475).toFixed(3));
console.log('type of res ', typeof res);
console.log('res ', res);
```

```js
var res = +(2.75 - 2.475).toFixed(3);
console.log('type of res, ', typeof res);
console.log('res, ', res);
```

```html
Open console.
```

> Floating-point arithmetic can only produce approximate results,
>   rounding to the nearest representable real number. When you perform a
>   sequence of calculations, these rounding errors can accumulate,
>   leading to less and less accurate results. Rounding also causes
>   surprising deviations from the kind of properties we usually expect of
>   arithmetic. For example, real numbers are associative, meaning that
>   for any real numbers x, y, and z, it’s always the case that (x + y) +
>   z = x + (y + z).

Answer (score 1):

The calculator round off the result automatically.

In javascript you have to do this yourself:

```js
type="text/javascript">alert(parseFloat((2.75 -
2.475).toFixed(5)));</script>
```